# Echo $_FILES giving no results

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple file upload while learning how to do so.

code looks as following:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
 <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>

<?php
    echo $_FILES["files"]['name']
?php
```

For some reason i get 0 results, I cant figure out why. I know that when I upload more files it'd be wise to run through them with a foreach loop, but for the sake of simplicity I'd rather have the results of 1 file first.

Comment: is the PHP snippet in upload.php?

Comment: Yes it is in upload.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your html like this

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Then in upload.php:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo try with

```
print_r($_FILES)
```

Also try to add to form tag code below

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming both the HTML form and PHP upload code is written within this file upload.php. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Change your form HTML to:

```
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> <!-- Form action can be omitted. enctype attribute is needed -->
   <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]"/>
   <br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="upload" name ="submit" /> <!-- Add name here -->
</form>
```

Modify your PHP code:

```
<?php 

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($_FILES);
   }

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Answer (score -1):

Correct html for you will be:

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]"/>
   <br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

it must work

You may also try:

```
var_dump($_FILES);
print_r($_FILES);
```

Comment: You should edit your existing answer instead of posting a new one with the same solution.